# Dynamically instantiate multiple copies of a MC

Tags: flash, actionscript, instantiation

I have aa question re:AS 3. I made a Post-It note movie clip that is draggable. I want to create a whole pad of notes, or at least simulate this. I thought the best way to do this would be to add another Post-It whenever the startDrag() is triggered.

I first tried creating the Post-It with symbols but didn't think I could dynamically create new ones this way. I then created a class and added it to the stage:

...
addChild(new PostItNote());

But I wasn't able to (or don't know how) to set the x, y position on the stage.

Anyone have suggestions on the best way to accomplish this or even another way altogether?

EDIT:

```
package  {

 import flash.display.MovieClip;
 import flash.display.Sprite;
 import flash.events.MouseEvent;
 import flash.events.Event;
 import flash.text.TextField;
 import flash.media.Sound;
 import flash.media.SoundChannel;
 import flash.text.TextFormat;

 public class CoinHitTest extends MovieClip {

  var count:Number = 0;
  var total_count:TextField;
  var hitting:Boolean = false;
  var coinSnd:Sound = new coin_drop();
  var myMoney:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
  var noteStack:Vector.<PostItNotes> = new Vector.<PostItNotes>();

public function CoinHitTest(){
    for(var $i:int = 0; $i <5;$i++)
{
    var newPostIt:PostItNotes = new PostItNotes();
    this.addChild(newPostIt);
    this.noteStack.push(newPostIt);
}
// constructor code
   coin.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, __handleCoinDown);
   coin.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, __handleCoinUp);

   total_count = new TextField();
   total_count.x = 795.20;
   total_count.y = 506.15;
   total_count.mouseEnabled = false;

   myMoney.size = 28;
   total_count.defaultTextFormat = myMoney;
   total_count.text = String("$" + count);
   addChild(total_count);
  }

  private function __handleCoinDown($evt:MouseEvent):void {

   coin.startDrag(true);
     coin.scaleX = 1.5;
     coin.scaleY = 1.5;
   addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, __checkHit);
  }

  private function __handleCoinUp($evt:MouseEvent):void {
   coin.stopDrag();
     coin.scaleX = 1;
     coin.scaleY = 1;
   removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, __checkHit);
  }

  private function __checkHit($evt:Event):void {
    if (this.coffee.hitTestPoint(coin.x,coin.y, false)) 
    { 
        // do our in-circle check
        if((coffee.x - coin.x) * 2 + (coffee.y - coin.y) * 2 <= (coffee.width/2 + coin.width/2) * 2)
        {
            stopDrag();
            coin.scaleX = 1;
     coin.scaleY = 1;
            removeChild(coin);
            coin.x = 116;
     coin.y = 380.1;
      addChild(coin);

        }
    }
    else
    {
        trace("Didn't Hit Mug");
    } 
   if (this.coin.hitTestObject(target)) {
     if (!hitting) {
         coinSnd.play();
     count++;
       total_count.text = String("$" + count);
       coin.stopDrag();

     removeChild(coin);
     hitting = !hitting;

     coin.x = 116;
     coin.y = 380.1;
      addChild(coin);
     coin.scaleX = 1;
     coin.scaleY = 1;

}
   } else {
    hitting = false;
   }
  }  

   }
}
```

EDIT:

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
public class PostItNotes extends Sprite{

        public function PostItNotes() {
            // constructor code
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem ist that you set PostItNotes as the BaseClass instead of the Class itself.

That means what you add to the stage is a Class that has only the logic and not the graphic elements.

What you need to do is go back to the symbol in the library -> right click -> properties and change the BaseClass to flash.display.MovieClip (or in your case flash.display.Sprite if you don't need the Timeline) and set PostItNotes as the Class.

**EDIT:**

```
package  {

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class PostItNotes extends Sprite {

        public function PostItNotes() {
            super();

            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onStartDrag);
        }

        protected function onStartDrag (event:MouseEvent):void {

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStopDrag);
            startDrag(false);

        }

        protected function onStopDrag (event:MouseEvent):void {

            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStopDrag);
            stopDrag();

        }
    }
}
```

I added the drag action to your PostItNotes class because I think this is where it belongs to as the drag really only concerns the post-it itself.

You probably have to remove the drag code where you had it before.

Do you need help on the creation of the new PostIt too?

Comment: Ok getting closer...I think. The problem is now that my drag and drop only works with the symbol I placed on stage, not the ones created in the code. I used the drag and drop code snippet on the symbol.

Comment: Edit your Question once more and post the Code for the PostItNotes class you created.

Comment: Ok I pasted my PostItNotes class. As you'll see it's empty because all that was in there was draw methods but since I am combining my symbol on the stage with the class I deleted them. should I have something in this class?

Comment: Thank you so much Mathias. Putting the drag/drop methods in the class was exactly what I needed. The Post it's were created using greatdecay's for loop but I couldn't see that until the drag/drop worked. BTW still getting used to stackoverflow. I'll try not to make future posts so junky and disorganized :)

Answer (score 0):

try creating a vector to hold references to your PostItNote objects...

Something like this:

```
var noteStack:Vector.<PostItNote> = new Vector.<PostItNote>();
for(var $i:int = 0; $i <5;$i++)
{
    var newPostIt:PostItNote = new PostItNote();
    this.addChild(newPostIt);
    this.noteStack.push(newPostIt);
}
```

And then you can just refer to an element in the vector whenever you want to be able to modify the properties of the PostItNote (x/y/z/whatever)

```
this.noteStack[0].x = 24;
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way: You can combine a AS3 class with a Symbol so that you can work with code and graphic within the same class.

That might be easier for you when you have to deal with the PostIt as a graphic element and all the logic written in ActionScript.

That way you can handle all the drag action within the PostIt Class itself.

Comment: Oh thank  you very much. Code woks well greatdecay and Mathias I'm really glad to learn this thank you :D

Comment: I'm gald we could help. But whenever one answer really answered your question please mark it as correct answer. This is somehow how this whole stackoverflow thing works ... :) Thanks.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see that:) I just finished implementing the code, and I thought it was going to work but once I did as you suggested and linked the symbol to my class, when I drag the class no new note is underneath. I put for(var $i:int = 0; $i <5;$i++)
{
    var newPostIt:PostItNotes = new PostItNotes();
    this.addChild(newPostIt);
    this.noteStack.push(newPostIt);
} I put this in my main class's consructor thinking it would create 5 right off the bat but no go.

Comment: Well it should create 5 PostIt. Could you maybe Post your whole main class in another answer her. Looking at the Code in more than one single line makes it a little easier to debug. (Maybe Post the Code of the PostItNotes as well) PS: Use the Code highlighting

Comment: Rather than posting the code in another answer, I would suggest editing the question and put the code there. I believe answers should be used for answers only, not for follow-ups on the question, here at stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks guys. I made the edit and posted my whole class. To combine the symbol with the PostItNotes class I right clicked the PostIt, convert to symbol, export to AS3, and put PostItNotes as my baseclass. The PostItNotes class is just an empty class with empty PostItNotes function.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this part of the question:

> I then created a class and added it to
>   the stage:
>
> ... addChild(new PostItNote());
>
> But I wasn't able to (or don't know
>   how) to set the x, y position on the
>   stage.

The most basic and common way of setting x and y of a new object you add like that would probably be to do something like this:

```
var newPostIt:PostItNote = new PostItNote();
newPostIt.x = 100;
newPostIt.y = 200;
addChild(newPostIt);
```

In other words, to keep a reference to the new object you create, instead of doing addChild(new PostItNote()), and set x and y and other properties before (or after) you add it to the stage.

Comment: Problem is Lars I need to create like 100 of them so creating them one by one would be time consuming with that method.